# Lose Life when Hit Ground

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was trying to create something like a lava floor in Unity 3D, like when the player falls and hit the ground they start losing life gradually, but my code does nothing.

Can someone help please?

```cs
    public GameManager manager;
    public Slider HealthBar;
    public float Health = 100f;
    public GameObject Plane;
    public float Dmg = 10f;

    void Start()
    {
        HealthBar.maxValue = Health;
        HealthBar.value = Health;
    }

    void Update()
    {
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(UnityEngine.Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "LavaGround")
        {
            Health -= Dmg;
        }

    public void TakeDamage(float amnt)
    {
        Health -= amnt;
        if (Health  <= 0f)
        {
            manager.GameOver();
        }
        float _h = Mathf.Clamp(Health, 0f, 100f);

        HealthBar.value = _h;
    }
```

Comment: Well you'll have to help diagnose this a lot, as this is not enough to go on see [mcve] and [ask] .. 

so, does your collider happen? is this a 2d game? are you sure the ground is tagged LavaGround, what makes you think it would lose health slowly,  you dont seem to use TakeDamage, nor does that seem to imply an over time aspect

Comment: It's a 3D game like I said. I only change the name of plane to LavaGround and the TakeDamage it was a test that i work out to lose life, I use something like keycode to take damage, but its not that that i want. I just want something like, hit object and take damage. 
I apologize i'm newby at unity

Comment: well if damage is happening twice.. thats what you told it to happen, so, you need to trace back what you did where you put stuff..

Comment: The problem is that: don't happen nothing. By now i have almost nothing to take damage. I saw some tutorials to lose life or take damage, but all tutorials just talk about damage from another character, like an enemy, my idea was something like the lava floor from minecraft, i know that I'll need (like you refer) lose health over time, what I don't now how to do, but right now I'm focusing just on losing life on hit something, in this case the floor (plane), I don't think that is very difficult but i don't know how to start coding. I only know the logic...

Comment: I'd like to see the code where one object hits the other...

Comment: It's the function (OnCollisionEnter), it was the one that i saw most peple using

Comment: I apologize, maybe I'm not very explicit, my English it's not perfect too. I'm really sorry. I'll try again..
I trying to build a simple code. I have one player and one path/route. My idea is:
When I fall from that path/route and drop on the floor, the player lose life, like the typical games. 
I'm new with unity so I'm trying to make things very very simple for later, when I get more familiar with this, improve the code.
At first i build one Function (TakeDamage) but I used a key, just to test how it works. But i want to take damage on hit objects (collision). Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

seems that nothing is happening because you are just adjusting the Health value in the

```
if (collision.gameObject.tag == "LavaGround")
    {
        Health -= Dmg;
    }
```

Please try to change it as

```
if (collision.gameObject.tag == "LavaGround")
    {
        TakeDamage(Dmg);
    }
```

to call TakeDamage method and check if health is below zero and update health bar.

Comment: Ok. I tried that and even change the Dmg to a negative value, but does nothing...

Comment: what do you mean by negative amount ? It should be positive since `TakeDamage` decreases current `Health` for the `Dmg` value, like `TakeDamage(10)`. Can you please try to debug the code ? Does `TakeDamage` method executed (is `collision.gameObject.tag == "LavaGround"` have `true` value when character is on lava)?

Comment: I updated and now, when hits the ground the (collision.gameObject.tag == "LavaGround") have true value but still don't lose health

Comment: @FernandoSilva does `HealthBar.value = _h`; executed (health bar value changes) ? Please adjust you character `Health` to have only half on the game start and check does lava affects the health indicator. Like `Health = Health /2;` in the `Start` method last line (to have indicator showing the half of health)

Comment: @FernandoSilva what is `Dmg` value btw? Is it initialized ? It should not be zero for sure.

Comment: I did some changes. I creat one new var, isIn (bool that checks if the player is on collision with the LavaGround). The player loses life when hit the ground but not continuously. I tried to put one while but it doesn't work.
  `void OnCollisionEnter(UnityEngine.Collision collision)
     {

        
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "LavaGround")
        {

            isIn = true;

            TakeDamage(Dmg);
            
           
        }
        if (collision.gameObject.tag != "LavaGround")
        {

            isIn = false;

        }
    }`

Comment: Consider using `compareTag` - won't solve the problem but is general advice.

Comment: @FernandoSilva with `collision.gameObject.tag == "LavaGround"` you should have `TakeDamage` method executed only when on lava. Do you have different `tag` values for lava, earth, sand and water surfaces ?

Comment: @oleksa i just have one tag, LavaGround, i don't have others. But with your advice and some others i could make it work. He lose life when hit the LavaGround, but now I need that the player loses life while on LavaGround. Like when he still one LavaGround loses life gradually..

Comment: @FernandoSilva Seems that you will need [the timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=netframework-4.8). It should be activated (and execute the `TakeDamage` each second) when character enters the lava and deactivated when it enters any other surface. Please check the

Comment: @oleksa its exactly that that I want! I checked the link but I'm not sure if i understood... sorry, could you explain how to use it please?

Comment: @FernandoSilva please check [this guide](https://owlcation.com/stem/Threading-Timer-In-C-Explained-With-Example) and ask new question if something is not clear